# ¿Cómo puedo sumar valores de 2 tablas agrupando por mes?

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas:

**`table1`**

```
date       | client | total
2015-01-01 | john   | 85.00
2015-02-01 | alfred | 35.00
2015-03-01 | georgy | 125.00
```

**`table2`**

```
date       | client | total
2015-01-01 | Wendy   | 25.00
2015-02-01 | Monique | 19.00
2015-03-01 | Jack | 14.00
```

Al necesitar unir estas tablas lo hago con esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT date, client, total from table1 
    UNION ALL SELECT date, client, total from table2) a where date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-11';
```

Y obtengo esto:

```
date       | client | total
2015-01-01 | john   | 85.00
2015-01-01 | Wendy   | 25.00
2015-02-01 | alfred | 35.00
2015-02-01 | Monique | 19.00
2015-03-01 | georgy | 125.00
2015-03-01 | Jack | 14.00
```

Hasta aquí bien pero ahora quiero agrupar estos valores por año, mes y sumando los totales y que me quede así:

```
year | month | total
2015 | 01    | 110.00
2015 | 02    | 54.00
2015 | 03    | 139.00
```

¿Cómo puedo modificar la consulta?

Comment: para sumar debes usar la funcion SUM(campo_a_sumar) en tu caso seria SUM(TOTAL)

Comment: paraa grupar es group by

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR(date)  year,
       MONTH(date) month,
       SUM(total)  total
    FROM (SELECT date, client, total 
                 from table1 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT date, client, total 
                 from table2
         ) a 
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-06-11'
    GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
    ORDER BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date);
```

Si `date` es efectivamente una fecha podemos usar [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) para obtener el mes de `date` y agrupamos por el mismo. Para el año hacemos lo mismo usando [`YEAR(date)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Comment: efectivamente es como dice @PatricioMoracho , adicional podrias agregar un alias al MONTH(date) para mejor presentacion de datos, pero la logica funciona y es correcta !!

Comment: es lo que quiere el usuario, lo que si debe tener en cuenta a modo de aprendizaje esta bien , pero cuando esa tabla crezca va a ser muy lento

Comment: Buen comentario @Tegito123

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Gracias! Funciona genial